# Is there a way to take numbers out of an input?

Tags: python

so imagine you make an `input()` saying Enter Age `input("Enter Age: ")` so a person wants to make an account saying "i am __ years old" is there a way to classify the number in the statement?
if so how would you do it? or is it even **Possible**?

Comment: Why not  force only a numeric input?

Comment: I never understand why to waste time for writing `i am __ years old`. It is simpler to write only number.